# My solution to $\int \sqrt{\tan(x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

$$\int \sqrt{\tan(x)}dx$$ let $u=\sqrt{\tan(x)}$ $$2\int \frac{u^2}{u^4+1}du$$ partial fraction decomposition $$-2\int\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}}{u^2+\sqrt{2}u+1} du+2\int\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}}{u^2-\sqrt{2}u+1}du$$ $$-2\int\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}}{u^2+\sqrt{2}u+1} du+2\int\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}}{u^2-\sqrt{2}u+1}du$$ $$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{1}{u^2+\sqrt{2}u+1} du+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{1}{u^2-\sqrt{2}u+1}du$$ $$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{1}{(u+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2+(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2} du+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{1}{(u-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2+(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2}du$$ and this part is where I differ from the rest of answers in this page, and hence why I posted this, just want to check if this method is correct as well. Let $u-\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\tan(\theta)$ and $u+\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\tan(\alpha)$ then $du=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\sec^2(\theta)$ and $du=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\sec^2(\alpha)$ $$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\sec^2(\theta)}{(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2})^2(\tan^2(\theta)+1)} d\theta+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\sec^2(\alpha)}{(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2})^2(\tan^2(\alpha)+1)}d\alpha$$ simplifying $$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}} d\theta+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}}d\alpha$$

Evaluating the integrals $$-\theta+\alpha=-\arctan\left(\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(\sqrt{\tan(x)}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\right)+\arctan\left(\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(\sqrt{\tan(x)}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\right)+C$$

Is this right? if it's not, please let me know where I did my mistake.

**Please don't suggest another method, I know a lot of alternative methods, but I'm not interested in those**

Comment: What happens when you undo your partial fraction decomposition? Do you still get $u^2$ in the numerator?

Comment: whoops, forgot about it, let me fix.

Comment: okay just for the sake of not fixing everything and typing all in latex, I've fixed it and it gives me now the correct answer, my fault.

Comment: You can change the size of the parentheses by `\bigl(..\bigr)` or `\left(..\right)`, which probably will make the equations easier to read.

Comment: In order to verify an antiderivative, just differentiate your solution and check if you get back to the original expression. Have you done (or tried) that?

Comment: In general, $\displaystyle\int \dfrac{1}{x^2+a^2}=\dfrac{1}{a}\arctan(x/a)+C$, so you can directly jump to your answer.